# let $A$ be a matrix $m\times n$ if The colums of $A$ Span $\mathbb{R}^m$ then the equation $Ax=b$ will have an answer for all $b\in \mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, independence

I can't understand why this is true, Intuitively, I thought that it should be the rows of A span all $\mathbb{R}^m$ , so they don't become zeros while row deducting.
Can someone help me understand this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $\vec b\in\mathbb R^m$. Let $\vec a_1,\ldots,\vec a_n\in\mathbb R^m$ be the columns of $A$. If $\vec a_1,\ldots,\vec a_n$ span $\mathbb R^m$, then we can write $$\vec b=x_1\vec a_1+\cdots+x_n\vec a_n$$ for some $x_i\in\mathbb R$. But this just says that there exists $\vec x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $A\vec x=\vec b$.

Basically, $A\vec x$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$ where the coefficients are the entries of $\vec x$.

Comment: Thanks, amazing explanation, now its alot more understandable.